# Is it possible to get the url or page reference from navigationMenuBase menuItems?

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura, navigation, menu, navigation-menu

In community builder I have set up a navigation menu, and I know in Aura I can fetch those items using `navigationMenuBase` and via JS have it navigate to those pages selected. I'm wondering if there is a way to get or generate the URL of the items directly?

Essentially, I'm trying to get around the fact that because you don't have valid href's for the template, the user is not able to right-click and open in a new tab (tab opens but is blank because the anchor link is not valid).  I know in LWC you can generate Url with a page reference, but the `v.menuItems` data that the aura component receives does not provide that information. Can the menuItems response be used at all to get the url data from SF? Or is there another method or variable navigationMenuBase provides that can be used?

Example response from v.menuItems:
`{id: 1, label: 'Case Management', active: false}`

Comment: from this documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/forceCommunity:navigationMenuBase/documentation you can pass the id from menuItems and call the javascript `component.getSuper().navigate(id);`

Comment: That navigates to the link, yes, but it does not provide the href to put into the html.  We are currently doing this, but we also need the href it evaluates to to place in the html to provide a valid Href on the anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of building a custom menu, but based on standard one, I was using connect API from frontend directly:

```javascript
export async function retrieveNavMenuItems(url,communityId,navigationLinkSetDeveloperName,addHomeMenuItem,sessionId) {
    let endPoint = `${url}/services/data/v50.0/connect/communities/${communityId}/navigation-menu/navigation-menu-items?navigationLinkSetDeveloperName=${navigationLinkSetDeveloperName}&includeImageUrl=true&addHomeMenuItem=${addHomeMenuItem}&publishStatus=Live`;
    let response = await fetch(endPoint, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${sessionId}`
        }
    })
    let parsedResponse = await response.json();
    return parsedResponse;
}
```

This will return something like this:

```json
{
    "menuItems": [
        {
            "actionType": "InternalLink",
            "actionValue": "/settings/XXXXXXX",
            "imageUrl": null,
            "label": "MenuItemZ",
            "subMenu": [],
            "target": "CurrentWindow"
        },
        {
            "actionType": "InternalLink",
            "actionValue": "/account/XXXXXXXX",
            "imageUrl": null,
            "label": "MenuItemY",
            "subMenu": [],
            "target": "CurrentWindow"
        },
        {
            "actionType": "InternalLink",
            "actionValue": "/membership",
            "imageUrl": null,
            "label": "MenuItemX",
            "subMenu": [],
            "target": "CurrentWindow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Hope this helps you to build your custom menu.

More Info: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_responses_navigation_menu_item.htm